# Scaling all compass sprites

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Is there a standard way to scale all the sprites created by compass? That is,  have a image which is double the resolution I need and I wish to have all sprites from that image be have the size. Currently I can do this by iterating over the loaded sprites and setting the `background-size` and modifying the `background-position`.

For clarity, by example, if I were using normal sized sprites I'd just do this:

```
@import "settings/*.png";
@include all-settings-sprites;
```

But to get the double sized sprites I have to do this:

```
@import "icons/*.png";
@include retina-sprites($icons-sprites); // retina sprites

@mixin retina-sprites($map) {
    $base-class: sprite-map-name($map);

    .#{$base-class}-all-retina-sprites {
      background-image: sprite-url($map);
      @include background-size(ceil(image-width(sprite-path($map)) / 2) auto);
    }

    @each $sprite in sprite-names($map) {
      .#{$base-class}-#{$sprite} {
        @extend .#{$base-class}-all-retina-sprites;

        $position: sprite-position($map, $sprite);
        background-position: nth($position, 1) nth($position, 2) / 2;
      }
    }
}
```

I'm hoping there's an easier or standard way to do this. The problem gets worse as I try to include individual sprites in the CSS file elsewhere since I can't use any of the standard definitions.